# Varying app size in google play console and play store

Tags: android, google-play, expo, google-play-console

I have an Expo app which is published in Google Play Store. I have build the anndroid app bundle (.abb) file and uploaded in google play console.

File size showing in google play console is around 24 MB.

[image: in Google Play Console app size is 24 MB]

But, when the app is published and I am downloading the app, it's 46 MB

[image: Google Play store says 46MB]

But when I actually download, while downloading its shows 39MB.

Why this change is size? Please explain.

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: I released the .abb file directly to Prod track. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the internal testing track, the APKs are not compressed and can thus be significantly bigger.

Consider reaching out to Play Developers support if you see this happening on other tracks persistently.

Comment: The screenshot from the app Store of 46mb is from production track only. I released to Test track and promoted to Beta and Production. Shall I try once with directly releasing to Production?

Comment: No, that wouldn't matter. If you had downloaded the app while it was  on a testing track before, there may be a cache in the play store. If you share the link I can tell you how much I see. Or try from another device / ask someone else if they're seeing the same size.

Comment: I released another app directly on prod track. it's 23MB now. Thank you for the info.